# Maintain aspect ratio of image while uploading

Tags: php, image-uploading

I am uploading image with PHP.
During upload i am resizing image from actual image to needed size.
But image size in not getting in its aspect ration according to width.

PHP Code.

```
$size = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
$ratio = $size[0]/$size[1];
$req_width = 500;
$height = $req_width* $ratio*2;

//after this code for re-size image with above dimension and upload image code.
```

**What i am doing wrong in formula.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you multiplying it by 2? And where does `$width` come from?

You should just be able to divide the required width by the ratio to give you the correct result.

```
$height = $req_width / $ratio;
```

Comment: I have just update the variable name.. 
ohhhh.... that was my big mistake.. :-( thankyou.. just wait for +1.. :-D